# Undefined reference to function even though it should be reachable

Tags: winapi, rust

Error message:

```
error: linking with `x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc` failed: exit code: 1
  |
<a lot of paths and args>
C:\Users\wikto\IdeaProjects\test/src/main.rs:297: undefined reference to `WaitForDebugEventEx'
```

Part of **main.rs**, I can share the rest if needed.

```
mod winapi;
use winapi::*;

unsafe fn debug_loop(&mut self, process_id: DWORD) {
    let mut continue_status = DBG_CONTINUE;
    let mut debug_event = std::mem::zeroed::<DEBUG_EVENT>();
    let debug_event = &mut debug_event;
    while WaitForDebugEventEx(debug_event, INFINITE) != 0 {
        //something
    }
}
```

Part of **winapi.rs**

```
#[link(name = "Kernel32")]
extern "C" {
    pub fn WaitForDebugEventEx(
        lpDebugEvent: *mut DEBUG_EVENT,
        dwMilliseconds: DWORD,
    ) -> BOOL;
}
```

Is there anything I'm doing wrong or maybe it's a problem with mingw32-gcc?

Comment: Try using `extern "stdcall"` or `extern "system"` instead of `extern "C"`.

Comment: [WaitForDebugEventEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-waitfordebugeventex) was introduced in Windows 10. Do you have the Windows 10 SDK installed and properly set up so that the linker can discover the import libraries? The 32-bit builds of MinGW are generally helplessly outdated.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes, according to VS Installer I have Win10 SDK 10.0.19041.0 installed. Another info that may be useful is that when I change `WaitForDebugEventEx` to `WaitForDebugEvent` the program builds properly. "properly set up" - I'm not sure about that, I just installed it via VS Installer

Comment: If `WaitForDebugEvent` gets properly resolved then that is a strong indication that the linker picks up *kernel32.lib* from a pre-Windows 10 SDK. You can use a tool like [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to learn from where *kernel32.lib* gets pulled in, and take it from there.